# In TextView printing goes wrong

Tags: java, android, android-intent, textview

Here is what my problem is: `onReceive` method gathers string message from `Intent`. I put this message into `ArrayList<String>` and print it in the `actual` TextView. Then I convert my `ArrayList<String>` into `String[]`. Lastly, I use `append` to print strings which are inside `String[] historiaA` into `history` TextView. **To understand, I provide snippet:**

```
public class NotificationCenter extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(EXTRA_MESSAGE)) {

    int counter = 0;

    ArrayList<String> historiaAL = new ArrayList<String> ();
    historiaAL.add(counter,intent.getExtras().getString("Message"));

    TextView actual = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.received_string);
    actual.setText(historiaAL.get(counter));

    TextView history = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.history_string);

    String[] historiaA = historiaAL.toArray(new String[historiaAL.size()]);

    history.append(historiaA[counter]);
    history.append("\n");               
    counter++;
    } 
}
}
```

What I want to achieve is to print every incoming message in my TextView. **What I actually get from provided code, assuming that:**

1. first incoming message is: **Hello**
2. second incoming message is: **World**
3. third incoming message is: **!!!**

is:

```
Hello
World
World
!!!
!!!
!!!
```

**What I am actually trying to achive is:**

```
Hello
World
!!!
```

What am I doing wrong? I worked that you on paper and it should provide me with the result that I intented to have.

**EDIT: Problmed solved. Turned out that, on each button click I was creating new `mNotificationCenter = new NotificationCenter();` each time which caused the trouble.**

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing a counter with a value of 0 each time your onReceive() is called.
So then with the line `historiaAL.add(counter,intent.getExtras().getString("Message"))` you are adding the new string at position 0 in your ArrayList.
At the end of the method you increment your counter, but `counter` is only a local variable. When you call onReceive() again, `counter` will again be newly created and set to 0 every time.

**`<Additional>`**
The code below handles the message as you intended, without un-necessary counters etc.
If you are still getting the undesired repeated words in your output, then it is because you are sending the message multiple times, or receiving one message multiple times.

```
public class NotificationCenter extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(EXTRA_MESSAGE)) {

            String receivedString = intent.getExtras().getString("Message");
            TextView actual = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.received_string);
            actual.setText(receivedString);

            TextView history = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.history_string);
            String historiaA = (String) history.getText() + "\n" + receivedString;

            history.setText(historiaA);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure. Sounds reasonable. Anyways, without using `counter` I am still getting what I was getting. Even if I go with `historiaAL.add(intent.getExtras().getString("Message"))` it does not change a thing.

Comment: Can you show the code where onReceive() is being called? I don't think it's the method itself that is causing this output.

Comment: I updated the whole class. I create `mNotificationCenter = new NotificationCenter();` inside one of the fragments class: `public class ReceiveSectionFragment extends Fragment`

Comment: Ok, it's a BroadcastReceiver. Run debug with a breakpoint where you set the "Message" extra. Check what value gets set here on each pass through. Is it sending the intent multiple times for the later strings?

Comment: `public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.receive.intent.MESSAGE";` It is just a constant so `onReceive` can run code assigned to desired thing. Also, I can not tell what you exactly meant...

Comment: "Message" is the name of the extra data. I'm talking about the **value** of the extra data. (1)Run debug. (2)inspect the value when the extra data is set. (3) press debug resume. (4) inspect the value when it stops again on the next pass. (5) repeat until you get a clear picture of what actual values are being sent each time.

Comment: In other words use debug to check whether your BroadcastReciever is receiving 3 intent messages "Hello", "World", "!!!" or is it receiving 6 messages "Hello", "World", "World", "!!!", "!!!", "!!!", or is it even receiving 3 messages "Hello", "World\n World", "!!!\n !!!\n !!!"

Comment: Seems like that this: `mNotificationCenter = new NotificationCenter();
                  registerReceiver(mNotificationCenter, new IntentFilter(EXTRA_MESSAGE));` was casuing trouble. Every time I pressed button, code above was called every time.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you register an new BroadcastReceiver each time in this way, you'll end up with multiple receivers, and each of them will receive the message and add the string extra to the TextView.